# FormattedText not working in UltraWinGrid

Tags: html, winforms, formatting, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using an UltraWinGrid to present a list of actions that have been taken.  This was originally a webapp, and is being converted to a winforms app, and the actions often have HTML formatting.  I've set the column to use FormattedText:

```
band.Columns["Result"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.FormattedText;
```

The only HTML tags here are bold and line break, both of which, according to everything I've seen online, should be rendered by the FormattedText cells.  But this is the result:[image]

Is there a trick to getting FormattedText to work?  Some other setting for the grid that this style is dependent on?  These are the settings I'm using on the grid:

```
UltraGridBand band = grd.DisplayLayout.Bands[0];
band.Override.CellDisplayStyle = CellDisplayStyle.FormattedText;
grd.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizing = RowSizing.AutoFree;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.CellMultiLine = DefaultableBoolean.True;
grd.DisplayLayout.ViewStyleBand = ViewStyleBand.Horizontal;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeCell = SelectType.None;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeRow = SelectType.Single;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.No;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowDelete = DefaultableBoolean.False;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False;
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.Reset();
grd.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowCellAppearance.Reset();
```

As you can see, I've even tried defaulting the whole grid to FormattedText, but without any change in results.  To make things just a little more confusing, line breaks are working in the *same* grid, but with a different item:
[image]

The only difference I can see is that this second example only has line breaks, while the first one combines line breaks and bold tags in the same cell.

Comment: Hi Lisa, according to the documentation provided by Infragistics, the content rendering isn't actually HTML, it's a proprietary XML format similar to HTML to make it easier and they advise to take a look at the `UltraFormattedTextEditorBase` Value property (https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.misc~infragistics.win.formattedlinklabel.ultraformattedtexteditorbase~value) for the formatting supported please take a look at: https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/winformattedlinklabel-formatting-text-and-hyperlinks

Comment: Thanks, Connor, but even according to your second link, it should be parsing the limited HTML I'm using.  I understand that it's not full HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a grid using the same modifications you have set for the grid in your example:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.CellDisplayStyle = CellDisplayStyle.FormattedText;
this.ultraGrid1.UseOsThemes = DefaultableBoolean.False;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizing = RowSizing.AutoFree;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.CellMultiLine = DefaultableBoolean.True;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ViewStyleBand = ViewStyleBand.Horizontal;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeCell = SelectType.None;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeRow = SelectType.Single;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.No;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowDelete = DefaultableBoolean.False;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = DefaultableBoolean.False;
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.Reset();
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowCellAppearance.Reset();
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.FormattedText;
```

This has given me the same result you are experiencing as seen below:

[image]

Which as you can see, is extracting some of the `html` tags inside of the text for the column, e.g: `<b><i><u><font>` but not applying the style correctly.

When I comment out the following line:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.CellDisplayStyle = CellDisplayStyle.FormattedText;
```

My Grid then renders correctly as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Connor, but I'm not sure how this:

band.Columns[columnIndex].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.FormattedText;

differs from this:

band.Columns["Result"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.FormattedText;

I know that's supposed to work.  But you can see in my post a screenshot of what it actually does.

Comment: I don't know if you're using a different version of the grid or if you've applied different settings to the grid, but for some reason, it's not working for me.

Comment: Hi @Lisa, my version is v20.2, the only other differences I can note are that I am not doing all the other changes to the grid that you are doing, I left everything default, I added in the following: `this.ultraGrid1.ResetDisplayLayout();` and then after setting the `.Style` I am calling: `this.ultraGrid1.Refresh();` they are the only differences I can see from the code you have provided, potentially the only other thing I can think of is that I'm using a `DataTable` and `DataColumn` of `typeof(string)` and I'm using the `columnIndex` instead of the `Name`, but I think it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have noticed that when I use all the modifications you have made to the grid, I am having the same results you are experiencing. (I will update my answer)

Comment: Thanks, Connor.  Removing that line of code did the trick.  Mostly.  I was still getting erratic results in some of the records in the grid.  It turned out that this renders as a link:

<a href="localhost/APRelayer.aspx?apitem=411872">

And this causes the entire field to be rendered as plain text, tags and all:

<a href="localhost/APRelayer.aspx?apitem=411872&isrej=1">

In fact, that &isrej=1 disables the FormattedText even if it isn't in a link.  Which seems like a bug to me.  I'm going to report it to Infragistics.

Comment: @Lisa Glad it helped! Yeah, I did notice some oddities with the formatting of text, hopefully if it is a bug it will be fixed relatively soon!